# Create sql database from xml python

Tags: python, xml, sqlite

I have a xml file with the data from a maya file using the minidom from xml.
i am trying to create a sqllite database using the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <object id="Car:Wheels_GRP">
        <Car:FrontWheels_GRP type="transform">
            <Car:Wheel_Front_L_GRP type="transform">
                <Car:Wheel_Rim_Front_L_MSH type="transform">
                    <Car:Wheel_Rim_Front_L_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                    <Car:polySurfaceShape4 type="mesh"/>
                </Car:Wheel_Rim_Front_L_MSH>
                <Car:Wheel_Front_L_MSH type="transform">
                    <Car:Wheel_Front_L_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                    <Car:polySurfaceShape5 type="mesh"/>
                </Car:Wheel_Front_L_MSH>
            </Car:Wheel_Front_L_GRP>
            <Car:Wheel_Front_R_GRP type="transform">
                <Car:Wheel_Rim_Front_R_MSH type="transform">
                    <Car:Wheel_Rim_Front_R_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                    <Car:polySurfaceShape6 type="mesh"/>
                </Car:Wheel_Rim_Front_R_MSH>
                <Car:Wheel_Front_R_MSH type="transform">
                    <Car:Wheel_Front_R_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                    <Car:polySurfaceShape7 type="mesh"/>
                </Car:Wheel_Front_R_MSH>
            </Car:Wheel_Front_R_GRP>
            <Car:Axle_Front_MSH type="transform">
                <Car:Axle_Front_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                <Car:polySurfaceShape8 type="mesh"/>
            </Car:Axle_Front_MSH>
        </Car:FrontWheels_GRP>
        <Car:BackWheels_GRP type="transform">
            <Car:Wheel_Back_L_GRP type="transform">
                <Car:Wheel_Rim_Back_L_MSH type="transform">
                    <Car:Wheel_Rim_Back_L_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                    <Car:polySurfaceShape9 type="mesh"/>
                </Car:Wheel_Rim_Back_L_MSH>
                <Car:Wheel_Back_L_MSH type="transform">
                    <Car:Wheel_Back_L_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                    <Car:polySurfaceShape10 type="mesh"/>
                </Car:Wheel_Back_L_MSH>
            </Car:Wheel_Back_L_GRP>
            <Car:Wheel_Back_R_GRP type="transform">
                <Car:Wheel_Rim_Back_R_MSH type="transform">
                    <Car:Wheel_Rim_Back_R_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                    <Car:polySurfaceShape11 type="mesh"/>
                </Car:Wheel_Rim_Back_R_MSH>
                <Car:Wheel_Back_R_MSH type="transform">
                    <Car:Wheel_Back_R_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                    <Car:polySurfaceShape12 type="mesh"/>
                </Car:Wheel_Back_R_MSH>
            </Car:Wheel_Back_R_GRP>
            <Car:Axle_Back_MSH type="transform">
                <Car:Axle_Back_MSHShape type="mesh"/>
                <Car:polySurfaceShape13 type="mesh"/>
            </Car:Axle_Back_MSH>
        </Car:BackWheels_GRP>
    </object>
</Data>
```

but when i am trying to read it using the code

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('D:/test.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('object')
print(len(itemlist))
```

i keep getting the error
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 4, column 2

any suggestion as how to read and create a sql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *unbound prefix* error is raised because the `Car` namespace is not defined in the xml.

Make this change to fix the problem:

```
<object id="Car:Wheels_GRP" xmlns:Car="http://schemas.blah.org">
```

The namespace url can be anything, but it must be included in the xml.

For converting the xml to a database, check this post:

[populating data from xml file to a sqlite database using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085430/populating-data-from-xml-file-to-a-sqlite-database-using-python)

Comment: yes that works fine.. but seems its better to remove the namespace when creating the sql database. So i changed the xml as
<Data>
 <object id="Car:Wheels_GRP">
  <transform name="Car:FrontWheels_GRP">
   <transform name="Car:Wheel_Front_L_GRP">

Comment: Will check how to create a sql database. Thanks for your help.